# Unknown character in variable

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a bash script to get some information from a remote host, but I got a problem, here is my code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -e

NODE_IP="192.168.136.1"
SSH_NODE="ssh -q -t -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@${NODE_IP}"

# check stack exists or not
stack=`${SSH_NODE} "openstack stack list |grep test | wc -l"`
echo -e "${stack}"
if [ "${stack}" == "1" ]; then
    echo -e "delete existed stack";
fi
echo -e "end"
```

Output:

> 1
>   end

The variable `stack` outputs 1 but it doesn't equals to "1", I guess there are some unknown characters behind it, so I tried to trim them by using `| xargs` and `| tr -d '\n'`, but both of them didn't work.

```sh
stack=`${SSH_NODE} "openstack stack list |grep test | wc -l | tr -d '\n' | xargs"`
# or trim after return
stack=`${SSH_NODE} "openstack stack list |grep test | wc -l" | tr -d '\n' | xargs`
```

If I change the code to "contains" instead of "equals", it will work.

```sh
if [[ "${stack}" == *"1"* ]]; then
```

**But I wonder what is the unknown character behind my variable.**

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Try `declare -p stack` to see what it contains, with special characters escaped.

Comment: Or, `printf '%q\n' "$stack"`, which displays nonprinting characters reliably actually more versions of bash. `declare -p` doesn't always do that right.

Comment: BTW, `echo -e` is a bad idea in general. Its behavior is wildly variable based on active runtime configuration; use `printf` instead, as the POSIX spec for `echo` recommends; also, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Comment: What does ```echo -e "${stack}" | hexdump``` result?

Comment: Thanks for all, I have some clues to troubleshoot this issue, @BenjaminW. `declare -p stack` shows `"eclare -- stack="1`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, `printf '%q\n' "$stack"` shows `$'1\r'`.

Comment: @BookOfZeus, `echo -e "${stack}" | hexdump` shows `0000000 0d31 000a 0000003`.

Comment: @Corey So, you got a carriage return in your variable. `tr -d '\r'` will remove it

Comment: @oguzismail Yeah, you're right, thanks!